# find command "finds" file I'm looking for but it doesn't exist

Tags: files, find, ls, macos

I am searching for a particular file so I use the `find` command and it finds the file that I'm looking for:

```
$ find / -name connect_power.aif 2>&1 | grep -v "Operation not permitted\|Permission denied\|No such file or directory"

/System/Library/CoreServices/PowerChime.app/Contents/Resources/connect_power.aif
/System/Volumes/Data/System/Library/CoreServices/PowerChime.app/Contents/Resources/connect_power.aif
```

Running `ls -l /System/Volumes/Data/System/Library/CoreServices/PowerChime.app/Contents/Resources/connect_power.aif`, I get the following.

```
ls: /System/Volumes/Data/System/Library/CoreServices/PowerChime.app/Contents/Resources/connect_power.aif: No such file or directory
```

Running `find / -name connect_power.aif -ls` yields:

```
1152921500311980401      240 -rw-r--r--    1 root             wheel              159358 Feb 29 03:49 /System/Volumes/Data/System/Library/CoreServices/PowerChime.app/Contents/Resources/connect_power.aif
```

So, according to the output, it's found the file in two different locations.  I can get to the first one, but I cannot get to the second.  Specifically, it "breaks" when I get to the `PowerChime.app` sub directory - it errors out and says it doesn't exist.  So, how did `find` find it and how can I get to it?

For the record, this is on macOS Catalina (10.15.5) but it's not a Apple/Mac centric question as I've run across this in FreeBSD as well.

Comment: Please run `ls -l /System/Volumes/Data/System/Library/CoreServices/PowerChime.app/Contents/Resources/connect_power.aif` and show us the results.  My suspicion is that the second hit is a broken link.

Comment: Same thing..."No Such File or Directory"  For the record, my `ls` command is aliased to `ls -laGh` so it includes hidden files as well.  I can't find seem to find anything at all

Comment: Thanks.  In that case, let's move on up the hierarchy and look at `\ls -lah /System/Volumes/Data/System/Library/CoreServices/PowerChime.app/Contents/Resources/`

Comment: IIRC applications on macOS are stored in a directory with some special properties that doesn't behave fully consistenty (maybe it's presenting the contents of an archive?).

Comment: Same thing @John1024 "No such file or directory"  In fact, `ls -lah /System/Volumes/Data/System/Library/CoreServices/` only shows a single directory named `CoreTypes.bundle`  The `PowerChime.app` doesn't exist and there are no hidden files.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' - macOS APFS presents two volumes one is read-only and the other is r/w.  The r/w volume (whatever you named your drive - i.e. Machintosh HD) is suffixed with " - Data"  The first directory in my output isn't on the "Data" volume

Comment: @Allan Thanks for the updates.  That's all interesting: I've seen nothing remotely like this on a Linux system.

Comment: No worries @John1024 - this is new to me too.  I'm just appreciative for the help!

Comment: Make sure that find command  is not aliased to the locate command. Also, segregate your stdout and  stderr and then examine which bucket the .aif file is in.

Comment: @RakeshSharma - find isn't aliased to anything.  When I first executed find, I did see it along with all the "Permission denied" errors, the line was exactly the same.

Comment: Does `find / -name connect_power.aif -ls` give the same error message?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick - no error message.  The output is in the question.  `find` seems to think the file is there.

Comment: Does `stat /System/Volumes/Data/System/Library/CoreServices/PowerChime.app/Contents/Resources/connect_power.aif` show any errors? If `find` and `stat` work but `ls` fails, we'll need to look at the `ls` executable to see if it has any unusual attributes.